# C++ how to have a thread helper

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, opos

I'm trying to refactor a DLL to control a OPOS device. After the device is claimed and enabled it starts a thread to constantly check for data received from the OPOS device. I declare the method in `OposReader.h`

But I figured it would be a better idea to pull out said method, and move it to a helper. So I created a class `ReaderThreadHelper.h` put it in... but in the thread  I have to adjust values in OposReader.

So in the OposReader I call `#include ReaderThreadHelper.h` and in the `ReaderThreadHelper.h` I have to do a `#include OposReader.h`... and that starts the problem with the circular reference... and I'm too new to C++ to know how to fix it.

Should I even have done this to begin with? Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: i'll accept your answer as soon as I can. You're right i put the include OposReader.h in my ThreadHelper.cpp and it worked :) me happy now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use forward declarations and include headers to `.cpp` files only.

Detailed explanation is here: [Resolve circular dependencies in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)